# How to conditionally groupby a column and transform a pandas dataframe on the basis of row wise operations?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe *df* of the form:

```
  id    start_time    end_time    label
  1      0               2         A
  1      3               6         C
  1      9               11        A
  2      0               4         B
  2      5               7         A
  3      1               10        C
  3      20              22        A
  3      22.5            24        A
```

I want to groupby column id based on the criteria that *end_time*(current row) - *start_time*(previous row)<= *threshold* and then get the corresponding times and labels as lists in a new dataframe. Effectively, for *threshold* = 2, the new dataframe after transforming *df* should look like:

```
  id    times                    labels
  1     [(0,2), (3,6)]           [A, C]  
  1     [(9,11)]                 [A] 
  2     [(0,4), (5,7)]           [B, A] 
  3     [(1,10)]                 [C]
  3     [(20,22), (22.5, 24)]    [A, A]
```

What is an efficient, pythonic way to achieve this?

The code for generating the sample df:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,0, 2, 'A'],[1, 3,6,'C'],[1,9,11,'A'],[2,0,4,'B'],[2,5,7,'A'],[3,1,10,'C'],[3,20,22,'A'],[3,22.5,24,'A']],columns=['id', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'label'])
```

Answer (score 5):

We need to use `groupby` with `shift` to create the sub group key , then we just do the `groupby` with `agg`

```
s=df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x : (x.start_time-x.end_time.shift(1)).gt(1).cumsum()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df['times']=list(zip(df.start_time,df.end_time))
df_out=df.groupby([df.id,s]).agg({'times':list,'label':list})
df_out
                         times   label
id                                    
1  0      [(0.0, 2), (3.0, 6)]  [A, C]
   1               [(9.0, 11)]     [A]
2  0      [(0.0, 4), (5.0, 7)]  [B, A]
3  0               [(1.0, 10)]     [C]
   1  [(20.0, 22), (22.5, 24)]  [A, A]
```

Comment: Thanks @YOBEN_S. Quick question, where do I provide the threshold value as input?

Comment: @Melsauce in the first line , gt(thresh)